# How to convert Object to array with custom format

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

This is my javascript Object

```
{
  username: 'hamet',
  weight: 75,
  active: false,
  data: {
     interestedIn: ['internet', 'ping pong'],
     anotherArr: [{data: [1,2,3] }],
     anotherObj: {
       // and another obj or array or any type of field
     }
  }
}
```

i need to convert this Object to array with following format

```
let arr = [
'username', 'hamet', 'username_type', 'string',
'weight', '75', 'weight_type', 'number',
'active', 'true', 'active_type', 'boolean',

'data.interestedIn', 'array', 'data.interestedIn_type', 'array',
'data.interestedIn.0', 'internet', 'data.interestedIn.0_type','string',
'data.interestedIn.1', 'ping pong', 'data.interestedIn.1_type','string',

'data.anotherArr', 'array', 'data.anotherArr_type', 'array',
'data.anotherArr.0.data', 'array', 'data.anotherArr.0.data_type','array',
'data.anotherArr.0.data.0', '1', 'data.anotherArr.0.data.0_type','number',
// ...
]
```

> i need this type of array to save data in redis with [hmset](https://redis.io/commands/hmset) command, also
> i won't use JSON.stringify for whole document

*the bad news is, none of the fields has constant value with constant data type,
maybe there is a object into object into object..*

Comment: possible using recursion and iterating over Object.keys()

Comment: yes it is possible with object.keys but the main problem is how to convert to array with that format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an iterative and recursive approach by iterating the properties and collecting nested properties and values.

```js
function getKeysValues(object) {

    function iter(o, p) {
        Object.keys(o).forEach(function (k) {
            var path = (p.concat(k)).join('.'),
                type = Array.isArray(o[k]) &&  'array' || typeof o[k];;
            if (o[k] && typeof o[k] === 'object') {
                result.push(path, type, path + '_type', type);
                return iter(o[k], p.concat(k));
            }
            result.push(path, o[k], path + '_type', type);
        });
    }

    var result = [];
    iter(object, [])
    return result;
}

var object = { username: 'hamet', weight: 75, active: false, data: { interestedIn: ['internet', 'ping pong'], anotherArr: [{ data: [1, 2, 3] }], anotherObj: { foo: 'bar' } } };

console.log(getKeysValues(object));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Without object as type

```js
function getKeysValues(object) {

    function iter(o, p) {
        Object.keys(o).forEach(function (k) {
            var path = (p.concat(k)).join('.'),
                type = Array.isArray(o[k]) &&  'array' || typeof o[k];

            if (o[k] && typeof o[k] === 'object') {
                if (type === 'array') {
                    result.push(path, type, path + '_type', type);
                }
                return iter(o[k], p.concat(k));
            }
            result.push(path, o[k], path + '_type', type);
        });
    }

    var result = [];
    iter(object, [])
    return result;
}

var object = { username: 'hamet', weight: 75, active: false, data: { interestedIn: ['internet', 'ping pong'], anotherArr: [{ data: [1, 2, 3] }], anotherObj: { foo: 'bar' } } };

console.log(getKeysValues(object));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: btw, you get an object for objects and not array, as in your example. you get array only for arrays.

Comment: do you mean this code will not work for this type of data? => obj: {data: [1,2,3]}

Comment: it works, but for objects, you have no information for the object. is it intended, or should it work like that, then i have to allow only array type.

Comment: your answer is worked but i have another problem, is there any way to restore this array to Object like before converted

Comment: you could read the array by using four consecutive items with information and build, depending on the type an array or object or some value property. proceed until all items are used. it would be easier, if you try it by yourself and ask a new question, if you have problems.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get a list of all the keys in your object. Then, combine it with [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof), to figure out the type of the value.

Something like

```
var output = [];
Object.keys(yourObject).forEach(function(key) {
  output.push(key);
  output.push(yourObject[key]);
  output.push(key + '_type');
  output.push(typeof yourObject[key]);
});
```

You need to do something different when you encounter an array as a value. I'll leave that up to you.

Comment: so when i encounter with object of object or any other difficult data type what should i do?

Comment: @HametGholizadeh
The most straightforward would be using recursion.
Make functions like `processObject`, `processArray`, `processValue`
and then delegate to those `if (yourObject[key] instanceof Object) { ... }`